# Source on counting lattice points on a line

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, lattices

Looking for a book or article on the result linked below. The result tells us that the number of lattice points on a line between points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is given by $\gcd(a-c,b-d)+1$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628117/how-to-count-lattice-points-on-a-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is essentially contained in Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*. On page 62:

> **Theorem 3.8** Two lattice points $(a, b)$ and $(m, n)$ are mutually visible if, and only if, $a - m$ and $b - n$ are relatively prime.

The proof of the theorem contains the proof of the counting result you are after.

Comment: Thanks, @prets!